# Pyplot returns different objects when plotting multiple lines in one plot()

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I want to use `fig.legend` with multiple labels. The example https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/figlegend_demo.html suggests that I should plot everything in a single `ax.plot(...)` call and then pass the handles as a tuple to `fig.legend(...)`.

However I have 9 individual lines and I want to generate them in a loop. If I initiate `handles = []` and then successively `handles.append(...)` all the lines, I get an error message like `UserWarning: Legend does not support [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x2ba353491f50>] instances.`

Upon investigation I found that the example from the above link generates objects which python calls `Lines2D(_line0) Line2D(_line1)` (note the missing reference to an address!). However if you plot only a single line in a `plot(...)`, then python generates these objects with reference to an address.

Minimal example:

```
### This is the one from the link, with additional 'print's

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.4, 0.7])
ax2 = fig.add_axes([0.55, 0.1, 0.4, 0.7])

x = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.02)
y1 = np.sin(2*np.pi*x)
y2 = np.exp(-x)
l1, l2 = ax1.plot(x, y1, 'rs-', x, y2, 'go')
print l1, l2

y3 = np.sin(4*np.pi*x)
y4 = np.exp(-2*x)
l3, l4 = ax2.plot(x, y3, 'yd-', x, y4, 'k^')

fig.legend((l1, l2), ('Line 1', 'Line 2'), 'upper left')
fig.legend((l3, l4), ('Line 3', 'Line 4'), 'upper right')
plt.show()
```

---

```
### This is the modified one with the lines plotted individually

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.4, 0.7])
ax2 = fig.add_axes([0.55, 0.1, 0.4, 0.7])

x = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.02)
y1 = np.sin(2*np.pi*x)
y2 = np.exp(-x)
l1 = ax1.plot(x, y1, 'rs-')
l2 = ax1.plot(x, y2, 'go')
print l1, l2

y3 = np.sin(4*np.pi*x)
y4 = np.exp(-2*x)
l3, l4 = ax2.plot(x, y3, 'yd-', x, y4, 'k^')

### Will produce the warning here:
fig.legend((l1, l2), ('Line 1', 'Line 2'), 'upper left')

fig.legend((l3, l4), ('Line 3', 'Line 4'), 'upper right')
### Final plot will contain an empty legend at the top left
plt.show()
```

Comment: `ax.plot()` always returns a list, which you have to unpack, so instead `l1 = ax1.plot(x,y1,'rs-')`, add a comma: `l1, = ax1.plot(x,y1,'rs-')`.

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why are you setting the legends separately? Why not pass them while plotting?

Comment: @Bazinga I think he want's separate legends like in the example he linked.

Comment: I think doing ax1.legend and ax2.legend separately should work